# Show that $G_{s}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Definition: $G_{s}:=\{g \in G: g.s=s\}$

My attempt is the following:

We take $g \in G$, and we consider this two sets:

$$gG_{s}:=\{gh:h\in G_{s}  \}$$
$$G_{s}g:=\{hg :h\in G_{s}\}$$

and we will prove that $gG_{s}=G_{s}g$, then let $x\in gG_{s}$, so $x=gh$ for some $h \in G_{s}$ ; given that $g \in G$ then $g^{-1}x=h$.

But then the things are not good because this equality does not help very much to show that $x=hg$ there has to be a better way to do this can you help me to prove this please? thank you :)

Comment: Is this $g.s=s$ for all $s$ in the set $S$ on which $G$ is acting, or just one element $s$?

Comment: yes @angryavian is the first part of te commment :)

Comment: Check that for $x\in G_S$, $gxg^{-1} \in G_S$.

Comment: with the equality above we have that $g^{-1}xg \in G_{s}$ isn't?

Answer (score 2):

If $g \in G_s$, we want to show that $hgh^{-1} \in G_s$ for any $h \in G$.

$$hgh^{-1}s=hg(h^{-1}s)=h(h^{-1}s)=s.$$

---

Edit for clarification: the statement is true if $G_s$ is defined to be the subgroup of group elements $g$ such that $g.s=s$ for **any** $s \in S$, by the above argument.

However, the notation $G_s$ is suggestive of another subgroup known as the stabilizer of $s$; it is the set of group elements $g$ such that $g.s=s$ for this particular element $s$. In general, this subgroup is not normal (see Hagen von Eitzen's answer). It would be best if you made sure which definition of $G_s$ you really want.

Comment: what happened with $g$ in this step ? hg(h−1s)=h(h−1s)

Comment: You use the fact that $g$ stabilizes any element of the set; in particular, $g.h^{-1}s=h^{-1}s$.

Comment: which is the definition  of stabilizez any element of the set ?

Comment: Well, for me the subscript suggests that only the element $s$ is fixed.

Comment: I dont undestand your comment @Berci :)

Comment: then all the above multiplications are actions isnt?

Comment: Is $s$ a fixed element of the set $S$ that $G$ acts on, or we require that elements of $G_S$ fix *all* elements of $S$? The answer uses the latter assumptions. The first one, however, seems not to be true (consider examples of the symmetric group)

Comment: then the above proof seems not true?

Comment: Neither the claim. (Consider the cycle $(234)$ in $S_4$, for example. This fixes $1$, but, its conjugate $(134)$ doesn't fix $1$.)

Comment: But: Is this g.s=s for all s in the set S on which G is acting, or just one element s? 
     
yes @angryavian is the first part of te commment :)

Comment: Ah, ok. Didn't pay attention. So, then $g$ fixes $h^{-1}\cdot s\in S$.

Comment: good then everything is right isnt?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g\in G_s$ and $h\in G$ then we want to show that $$hgh^{-1}\in G_s$$
in other words $hgh^{-1}(s)=s$ for any $s$, but $g\in G_s$ so $gh^{-1}=h^{-1}$ therefore
$$hgh^{-1}(s)=h(gh^{-1})(s)=(hh^{-1})(s)=1\cdot s=s$$

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is simply not correct in general.
Let $G=S_5$ acting by definition on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and let $s=5$. Then $G_s\approx S_4$ which is not normal in $S_5$. (Works with $S_3$ and $S_2$ as well).

More generaly: If $h\notin G_s$ and $hs=t$, say, with $t\ne s$. Then $hG_sh^{-1}=G_t$ and for most group actions this is $\ne G_s$.

Comment: but $G_{s}$ is the isotropy of a given element $s \in S$

Comment: What do you mean  "but"?

Comment: Im giving the reason why this should be correct :)